# Check FastCGI-enabled version of lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I have installed lighttpd and added script.fcgi to /var/www/html/ with chown and chmod and edited etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf like mentioned below and got:

> 2021-06-09 22:05:27: server.c.1513) server started (lighttpd/1.4.59)
> 2021-06-09 22:05:27: gw_backend.c.475) unlink /tmp/script.sock-0 after connect failed: Connection refused
> 2021-06-09 22:05:27: gw_backend.c.325) child exited: 127 unix:/tmp/script.sock-0
> 2021-06-09 22:05:27: gw_backend.c.601) gw-backend failed to start: /var/www/html/script.fcgi
> 2021-06-09 22:05:27: gw_backend.c.603) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.  If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags.  If this is PHP, try removing the bytecode caches for now and try again.
> 2021-06-09 22:05:27: gw_backend.c.1655) [ERROR]: spawning gw failed.
> 2021-06-09 22:05:27: server.c.1517) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.

The .conf is:

```
server.modules += (
"mod_dirlisting",
"mod_staticfile",
"mod_fastcgi"
)
fastcgi.debug = 1
fastcgi.balance = "least-connection" 
fastcgi.server = (
"/hello" => ((
"bin-path" => "/var/www/html/script.fcgi",
"socket" => "/tmp/script.sock",
"check-local" => "disable",
"max-procs" => 1,
))
)
```

Please, help to fix it. I am using Ubuntu and it is not PHP.

Comment: I have found solution here [https://serverfault.com/questions/120233/how-to-configure-fastcgi-to-work-with-ligttpd-in-ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/120233/how-to-configure-fastcgi-to-work-with-ligttpd-in-ubuntu)